# Error 429 when using the python module instabot with any online IDE?

Tags: python, replit

I am trying to use the module "instabot" to automate instergram 24/7. Ive been trying to use online IDEs like replit to run online 24/7 so I dont have to leave my computer on but the same error keeps occuring. (error 429) Is there a way to stop this from happening or another way of keeping code running online? Thanks

```
from instabot import Bot


bot = Bot()

bot.login(username="your username", password="your password")

print("logged in")
```

Comment: IG may not allow logins from replit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MattDMo How would instergram know that that the requests are coming from a replit?  As stated its a 429 error which means there are too many requests. I dont know how to solve the problem.